# Using data from forms / filled boxes and use them in a a link for an API request

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, api, get

i would like to use 2 boxes to fill 2 settings of an API link. To get the data, i used a GET request.
Each of the boxes are, in that case the user_id and the second one is the beatmap_id, and they have to fill the two parameters:"u=" and "b=".
In order to do that, i created in the HTML 2 fillables buttons and one clickable.
and in the JS, i used getElementById.value for both user_id and beatmap_id and made an AJAX GET request

Here's the code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=\, intial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" Content="ie=edge" />
        <Title>Fetch JSON from API and map lat lon</Title>
        <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet'>
        <style>


            html, body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
                font-family: 'Montserrat';font-size: 22px;;
                color: white;
                text-align: center;
                }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1> Osu! Thumbnails </h1>

            <br></br>

            <input type = "text"
            id = "user_id"
            placeholder = "user_id"
            value = " " 
            class="c1"/>


            <input type = "text"
            id = "beatmap_id"
            placeholder = "beatmap_id"
            value = " " 
            class="c2"/>

            <br></br>
            <br></br>


            <input type="button"
            id = "Submit"
            value="Submit" 
            class="c3" >
        </header>

        <div id="animal-info"></div>

        <script src="js/main.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

and here is the JS:

```
function getValue(){
  var user_id = document.getElementById("user_id").value;
  var beatmap_id = document.getElementById("beatmap_id").value;
  var Submit = document.getElementById("Submit");
}
Submit.addEventListener("click", function() {




var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
ourRequest.open('GET', 'https://osu.ppy.sh/api/get_scores?k=MyApiKey&u='+user_id+'&b='+beatmap_id+'.json');
ourRequest.onload = function() {
    var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);


    renderHTML(ourData);    
    console.log(ourData)

};
  ourRequest.send();
});`enter code here`

function renderHTML(ourData) {};
```

Also, i censored my Api key just to be safe, sorry if this causes any problems

Comment: i'm not sure what your question is. can you edit your post to provide a question or problem you are having with your code?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are never getting the values of the inputs. Your getValue() function doesn't return anything. It should return an array of values atleast. In your click listener, you should retrieve the values of the inputs by calling the getValue() function. In the listener function, user_id and beatmap_id are not even defined variables.

Try calling your getValue() function in the listener and making it return an array.